# simple mysql query to access data fields in Drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have got some trouble with Drupal 7. What I want to do is read out all field_data_fields of one objects with php.

Example: I need to show a CAR Entry and I need to access
field_data_field_speed
field_data_field_size

etc.

The Problem is that I can't find out where all this field entries are connected to an object id. Is there maybe a very easy solution to get all fields connected to an object id?

Anyone who knows Drupal and can help me? :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) should save you lots of time

EDIT: Adding a sample you could refer to

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'car')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1); //Remove to include unpublished content
$result = $query->execute();

$nids = array_keys($result['node']);

if(!empty($nids)){

    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

    foreach($node as $car_node){
        $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $car_node);

        //FINALLY! Here we can get the value of the field you need
        $size = $node_wrapper->field_size->value();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use "views" module than to write your own queries. It's, let's say, standard in Drupal development:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views